# Redeploying automatically without "mvn:redeploy"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a mavenized dynamic web project in Eclipse.  When I make changes to it, I must call `mvn:redeploy` to redeploy the project into Tomcat.  Is there a way to automatically redeploy to Tomcat when saving files, without the need of `mvn:redeploy` command?

Answer (score 1):

Use Eclipse's "[Java - On Save Actions](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-save-actions.htm)" to configure additional action which will invoke `mvn redeploy`.